# How to connect azure analysis services with azure sql db for 250GB table size data?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-analysis-services, azure-sql-reporting

we have a view which generated around 250GB data and connected with power bi but the performance is bad. Now we are thinking to connect this view via azure analysis services and connect with power bi.

But when i see the pricing tiers there is no such tier to cache 250GB. 
Could anyone suggest me on this.

Comment: Did you do an import in Power BI or direct query? Also you don't store all 250 GB it will be highly compressed. I would suggest building the model in SSDT and seeing how large it is in memory before getting AAS setup.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Analysis service price tier  S9 support you cache the 250GB data:
[image]

You could reference: [Azure Analysis Services pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/analysis-services/)

support Azure SQL database is [Supported Data source in Azure Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-datasource) :
[image]

> How to connect azure analysis services with azure sql db ?

You can reference this tutorial:

1. [Using Azure Analysis Services over Azure SQL DB and DW](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/using-azure-analysis-services-over-azure-sql-db-and-dw/).
2. [Creating your first data model in Azure Analysis Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-mx/blog/first-azure-as/)

Create a sample data model to get data from Azure SQL database with SSDT or Visual Studio, then deploy the model to Azure Analysis Service. After the deployment finished, you could connect to the Azure Analysis Service from Power BI.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just as a heads up, S9 isn't available in all regions. Someone else suggested to load the model and see how big it is. AS does compress the data. Finally, keep in mind that if you process the model you need some memory overhead for the model to fully process.